# Getting max volgnr in nested object graph

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code :

```
void Main()
{
    Order order = new Order
    { 
        Catalogen = new List<Catalog>
        {
            new Catalog
            {
                Artikels = new List<Artikel>
                {
                    new Artikel{PosNr=1}, new Artikel{PosNr=2}, new Artikel{PosNr=3}
                }
            },
            new Catalog
            {
                Artikels = new List<Artikel>
                {
                    new Artikel{PosNr=1}, new Artikel{PosNr=2}, new Artikel{PosNr=6}
                }
            }
        } 
    };

    int max=1;
    try
    {
        max = order.Catalogen
            .Where(c => c.Artikels.Count > 0)
            .Max(c => c.Artikels.Max(a => a.PosNr)) + 1;
    }
    catch(Exception Ex)
    {
        max = 1;
    }

Console.WriteLine (max);
}

class Artikel {
    public int PosNr;
};

class Catalog {
    public List<Artikel> Artikels;
};

class Order {
    public List<Catalog> Catalogen;
}
```

Is there a more simple way to get the max posnr taking into account that an ordercatalog can be empty ? The where seems to be needed to consider this fact but it makes the code look clunchy so I am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var q = from cataloog in order.Catalogen
        from artikel in cataloog.Artikels
        select artikel.Posnr;

var max = q.Max() + 1;
```

Alternatively

```
var max = order.Catalogen.SelectMany(c => c.Artikels).Max(a => a.Posnr) + 1;
```

Update:

Of course, if there are no Artikels, than the maximum Posnr is undefined, which is reported by `Enumerable.Max` as an `InvalidOperationException`.

In your specific case, there is an easy solution for that:

```
var max = order.Catalogen.SelectMany(c => c.Artikels)
    .Select(a => a.Posnr)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Max() + 1;
```

Comment: if all catalogen are empty this does not work so if i do the max statement in a try catch block i can make it work taking this border condition into account. You put me on the right track. SelectMany is something i did not use before and is worth reading a bit about. Linq can be daunting sometimes.

Comment: excellent solution. The defaultifempty saves me from the try catch block. Thank you for your effort.